# Store values in a shared theano tensor variable to a numpy variable

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, theano

I am trying to store the values of a shared theano tensor variable into a numpy variable.

xyz is a numpy variable
and W is a shared theano tensor variable

tried using eval

```
    xyz = self.W.eval()
for i in range(0,xyz.shape[0]):
            for j in range(0,xyz.shape[1]):
                #print(xyz[i][j])
                #print(i)
                xyz_temp[i][j]=(xyz[i][j]*10)/10   // just trying to do some random operation on the values
```

but it returns an error as

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'eval'

Comment: The error is literally telling you that W is a numpy ndarray, not a theano tensor.

Comment: but W is a tensor variable and if i remove the eval function i get an error "'TensorVariable' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: That makes no sense, include then the complete stack trace / error message and the code that produces it.